# Таймер в RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Как в `RabbitMQ` на `python` сделать отправку сообщений в очередь так, чтобы оно пришло в очередь только через определенное время, например, 4 часа ?

Comment: [Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ не поддерживает такую "родную" функцию.

Предложение приведенное [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559808/218684) проблематично так как требует базы данных и постоянную обработку сообщений. Такое решение намного более "рискованно". Не говоря уже о том что просто дополнительное обрабатывающее средство + база данных ну просто ни к чему.

Но функцию возможно эмулировать. При этом сообщение будет отослано и будет находиться на сервере до тех пор пока не наступит время сообщение доставить. [Следующая версия](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/pull/329) NServiceBus.[RabbitMQ](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/) транспорта будет поддерживать Native Delays при помощи Topic Exchanges.

Имплементация не зависит от языка посылающей аппликации.

Идея заключается в создании header exchanges где каждый уровень представляет бит из задержки. Если бит 0, exchange направляет сообщение на следующий уровень. Если бит 1, то в queue с TTL соответствующий задержке на этом уровне. Каждый queue с DLQ binding к следующему exchange.

Схематически, это будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметка: можно также имплементировать с Header Exchanges

С 32-ух битной задержкой (32 уровня exchanges) задержка получится от 1 до 2^31 секунд.

Comment: Добавленна документация: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/delayed-delivery

Comment: Я бы вместо подобных упражнений просто выделил по очереди на каждую возможную величину задержки - обычно их не должно быть очень много.

Comment: Как сказать. Разбежка может быть порой достаточно серйозной. Наша клиентура не работает с очередями на прямую, поэтому их этот вариант устраивает больше. Кроме того, администраторам по душе стандарт в имплементации. На вкус и цвет товарищей нет 

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение попадёт в очередь как только вы его туда отправите..

Что то вы намудрить хотите. Тогда уже добавляйте дату в сообщение и при чтении из очереди если 4 часа не прошло - отправляйте клон задачи в конец очереди, текущую завершайте.

Или, пишите в какую-нибудь промежуточную таблицу в базе данных. Читайте её постоянно (например, по крону). Когда выгребутся сообщения с нужной датой - - создавайте задачу в очередь а строку из базы удаляйте:)

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличный плагин, который позволяет это реализовать - **Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ**.

### Пример использования (Java)

Определим точку обмена:

```
// ...
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
channel.exchangeDeclare("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
// ...
```

Добавим пару сообщений:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = "delayed payload".getBytes("UTF-8");
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("x-delay", 5000);
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().headers(headers);
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "", props.build(), messageBodyBytes);

byte[] messageBodyBytes2 = "more delayed payload".getBytes("UTF-8");
Map<String, Object> headers2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers2.put("x-delay", 1000);
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props2 = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().headers(headers2);
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "", props2.build(), messageBodyBytes2);
```

Задержка указывается в заголовке сообщения (x-delay) в секундах, соответственно.

Больше примеров и информации можно найти на странице самого проекта - [Scheduling Messages with RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).